# Syntax error for down()?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner computer science student and using python in computer science 1. My assignment is to write a program that creates a spirograph. I think that the code is all right to do that, but when i run it, an error message pops up that says syntax error and it highlights `down()`, which is a common turtle command. I have no idea why. It said syntax error for `main()`, but then i restarted python and now it says there's an error in `down()`. Here's the code:

```
from turtle import *
from math import *

def xValue(R,r,p,t):
    x=(R-r)*cos(t)-(r+p)*cos((R-r)/r*t)

def yValue(R,r,p,t):
    y=(R-r)*sin(t)-(r+p)*sin((R-r)/r*t)

def initialPosistion():
    t=2*pi
    up()
    goto(xValue(R,r,p,t),yValue(R,r,p,t)
    down()

def iterating(R,r,p):
    t = 2*pi
    while t < 0:
        t = t-0.01
        goto(xValue(R,r,p,t),yValue(R,r,p,t)
    up()

def main():
    R = 100
    r = 4
    p = int(input("Enter p(10-100): "))
    if p < 10 or p > 100:
        input("Incorrect value for p!")
    iterating(R,r,p)

input("Hit enter to close...")

main()
```

Answer (score 3):

Missed a closing `)` at the end of this line:

```
goto(xValue(R,r,p,t),yValue(R,r,p,t))
```

Comment: wow, i apologize for being so stupid...